# How do you get/create angular package.json scripts?

Tags: json, angular, package.json

I looked on the angular.io site but I can't find the package.json files under additional documentation.

How is this created?, do I need to download it somewhere?.

Comment: I removed the resource request (since package.json is not something you download) and resource request are off-topic on StackOverflow. You should see package.json as a settings file for angular, this file is automatically created and updated by angualar (normally you do not need to edit), instead learn how to create new projects with ng command.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Vineela's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52630761/4488232):

If you want to create and manage you angular application using the [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki), you must first configure the Angular CLI in your local environment:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Only after you have the Angular CLI installed globally, can you generate a new project which will contain all of the scripts for the project within your (generated) package.json, similar to what rhavelka shared in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52630722/4488232).

`ng new my-project`

Generated package.json from Angular CLI: 6.0.7 (note the default scripts):

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.6",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: so thankful for your help

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project with command "ng new projectname" Angular will create the package.json file for you.